# I made a User validation program using servlet and JDBC but its not working

Tags: java, validation, servlets, jdbc

I am making a program for user validation using servlet and JDBC in eclipse. Where the user will enter his username and password in HTML form, these parameters will be searched in the database and if a user with entered username and password exits the user will be promoted to next page. My project setup looks like this I have added MySQL connector jar and servlet API jars only

[image]

```
String name = request.getParameter("username");  
String password = request.getParameter("userpass");  

if(LoginDao.validate(name, password)){  
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Weclome.html");  
    rd.forward(request,response);  
}  
else{  
    out.print("Sorry username or password error");  
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");  
    rd.include(request,response);  
}  

out.close();
```

This is inside validate() method :

```
public static boolean validate(String name,String password){  
boolean status=false;  
    try{  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ankit","root","root");  

    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( "select * from usereg where name=? and pass=?");  
    ps.setString(1,name);  
    ps.setString(2,password);  

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();  
    status = rs.next();  

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        }  

    return status;  
}
```

But every time I run the program I get 404 error:
Message /LoginForm/FirstServlet
Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: How did you tell the container to map the url to the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your `RequestDispatcher` declaration? I suppose you have missed the correct spelling of your html file as `Weclome.html` instead of `Welcome.html`